# special classes of ideals (eg. toric) that admit faster Buchberger algorithm?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, computational-complexity, computational-geometry

I have heard that toric ideals allow one to speed up the Buchberger algorithm considerably (see [Grobner bases of toric ideals, Remark 2,3](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00074446/document)). My question is two-fold:

- What are the precise complexity-theoretic bounds known for the Buchberger algorithm for toric ideals?
- Are there other non-trivial classes of  ideals on whom a grobner basis can be computed efficiently? Can you please provide a reference to them?

For context, I wish to use a grobner basis as a way to encode [dataflow analysis problems](https://github.com/bollu/bollu.github.io#dataflow-analysis-using-grobner-basis) in compiler construction, in a manner that allows mutiple analyses to "share" information easily. So, knowing special types of ideals and fast algorithms to compute their Grobner basis woud help design specific dataflow analyses.